# how to match variables in one dataframe by grouped observations in another dataframe

Tags: r

Consider:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    row.names = c('Obs1','Obs2','Obs3','Obs4'),
    V1 = c(1,2,1,0),
    V2 = c(0,0,1,0),
    V3 = c(1,1,0,3))

df2 <- data.frame(
    Group = c("A", "A", "B"),
    Obs = c("Obs1", "Obs2", "Obs3"))
```

I want to match the observations that make up each `Group` of `df2` to each variable in `df1` and return a dataframe that describes if the observation is present or not - ultimately to be able to classify which `Group`s the variables of `df1` should be included in. All observations that make up a `Group` must have a value > 0 in `df1` for the variable in `df1` to be considered part of the `Group`.

```
output
      Group V1 V2 V3
1         A  1  0  1
2         B  1  1  0
```

Comment: Would you mind putting what your expected output is?

Comment: Why is `Obs2  2  0  1     A` omitted from the output? I don't clearly understand what do you mean by  `All observations that make up a Group must have a value > 0 in df1 for the variable in df1 to be considered part of the Group`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way:

```
library(dplyr)
df1$Obs <- rownames(df1) # rownames are a pain, let's have a real column
# complains because of a factor in df1, but no biggie:
output <- inner_join(df1, df2) 
output %>% 
     group_by(Group) %>% 
     summarize_at(
       vars(starts_with('V')), 
       function (x) as.numeric(any(x>0))
     )
```

This gives the output you required.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table` to join the two datasets on 'Obs/rn', grouped by 'Group', check if `any` of the values are greater than 0 in the columns

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, keep.rownames=TRUE)[df2, on = .(rn = Obs)
    ][, lapply(.SD, function(x) +any(x > 0)) , Group, .SDcols = V1:V3]
#   Group V1 V2 V3
#1:     A  1  0  1
#2:     B  1  1  0
```